# Analytics Builder - Incorrect Email Metrics

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, reporting, analytics, custom-report-type

Whenever we pull an email send report using the 'Recent Email Send Summary Report' we have particular jobs whose delivery rates are lower than their open rates. often the delivered counts are 1 or 2 out of 200, while the open rates remain accurate e.g. 50, 60, etc. Is there a workaround in place for this? Looks like it's only affecting certain emails.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing some of the tracking terms in the [Recent Email Send Summary Report](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_re_recent_email_sending_summary_report.htm&type=5).

> Deliverability Rate:  Percentage of Emails Delivered
>
> Open Rate:    Percentage of Emails Delivered that were Emails Opened

Comment: I wish I was confusing terms. Unfortunately, therein lies the problem. Whenever we pull in a certain report, it says that the those delivered are usually 1 or 2, whereas the opens are accurate, usually around 40% depending on send. Have you run into this reporting issue previously?

Comment: If 2 were delivered and only 1 opened, then you'll have a 50% open rate.

Comment: Sorry wasn't clear with my example. Say we sent 100 emails. Our report will show 1 delivered with 50 opens, and 25 click throughs. So all metrics are correct except for deliverability. Not sure if it's a server issue. Any thoughts?